# Help accessing this multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i have this array

```
    Array
(
    [disc-art] => Array
        (
            [original] => upload/c/4/c4eea45ce0f5e8d5698f5ff2d18b4566.jpg
            [preview] => Array
                (
                    [dvd-disc] => upload/c/4/d_disc_c4eea45ce0f5e8d5698f5ff2d18b4566.jpg
                )

        )

    [cover-art] => Array
        (
            [original] => upload/7/2/72bb5a03708c99c822a792c76c00e8d1.jpg
            [preview] => Array
                (
                    [dvd-cover] => upload/7/2/d_cover_72bb5a03708c99c822a792c76c00e8d1.jpg
                    [dvd-spine] => upload/7/2/d_spine_72bb5a03708c99c822a792c76c00e8d1.jpg
                    [dvd-back] => upload/7/2/d_back_72bb5a03708c99c822a792c76c00e8d1.jpg
                )

        )

    [insert-art] => Array
        (
            [original] => upload/b/1/b1f8e49d77121c01011acaa90cabc8ee.jpg
            [preview] => Array
                (
                    [dvd-insert] => upload/b/1/d_insert_b1f8e49d77121c01011acaa90cabc8ee.jpg
                )

        )

    [boxshot] => Array
        (
            [preview] => Array
                (
                    [boxshot] => upload/7/2/d_boxshot_72bb5a03708c99c822a792c76c00e8d1.jpg
                )

        )

)
```

I want to return an array that accesses each `preview` and gets the contents

```
array('dvd-disc' => '...path...', 'dvd-cover' => '...path...', etc...)
```

Please help, it has been a long day and I want to go home! :)

**EDIT:**

Correction - I want my final array to look like this...

```
array(
    'dvd-disc' => '<img src="'.$path.'" alt="'.$type.'" />',
    'dvd-cover' => '<img src="'.$path.'" alt="'.$type.'" />', 
    etc...
);
```

where `$path` is the value of each `preview's` sub-value and $type is the value of each `preview's` sub-key

Comment: *"I want to go home!"*: You could still post what you have tried, or what your particular problem is ;) Don't you know how to access the elements? Or how to combine them?

Comment: @Felix Kling Sorry, I have tried to accomplish the problem to no avail with foreach loops and `array_push`, but I can't seem to wrestle this one down.

Comment: What are you looking for for $type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($main_array as $sub_array)
{
   if(isset($sub_array['preview']))
   {
       foreach($sub_array['preview'] as $type => $image_url)
       {
           $new_array[$type] = '<img src="'.$image_url.'" alt="'.$type.'" />';
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Tim - you answered my original question, but my brain is fried and that actually wasn't what I was looking for. Should I ask a new question, or can you edit yours here?

Comment: @Dave: That should do it now.

Answer (score 2):

```
// (the array you are bring in is $mainArray)

// New array we'll be creating
$previewPaths = array()

foreach ($mainArray as $item) {

    foreach ($item['preview'] as $previewName => $previewPath) {

        $previewPaths[$previewName] = '<img src="'.$previewPath.'" alt="'.$previewName.'" />',;

    }

}
```